# Update specific row with accurate data on a foreach loop Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i'm having problem on my update query using foreach loop, it updates on a right row but when i click the button below of my other buttons(approval button) it is not inserting the right data on my column approvalStat and status, but updates gets the data from the latest row, kindly help me guys, thanks!

VIEWS:

```
 <?php } else { foreach($getNoti as $row): $id = $row->id; $timeStat = $row->status;  $approveStat = $row->ApprovalStat; ?>
              <tr>
                <input type="hidden" name="approval" value="<?php echo $row->ApprovalStat ?>">

                <input type="hidden" name="userID" value="<?php echo $row->id ?>">
                <td class="tn-ixdt"><?php echo $row->name ?></td>
                <td class="tn-ixdt"><?php echo $row->status ?></td>
                <td class="tn-ixdt"><?php echo $row->dateToday ?></td>
                <td class="tn-ixdt"><?php echo $row->timeIn ?></td>
                <td class="tn-ixdt" style="text-align:right;"><button class="approveStat" name="approveStat" value="<?php echo $row->timeId ?>"><img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/ico-approve.png'); ?>"></img></button><button class="deleteStat" name="deleteStat" value="<?php echo $row->timeId ?>"><img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/ico-delete.png'); ?>"></img></button></td>
              </tr>
              <?php endforeach; } ?>
```

Controller

```
 elseif (isset($_POST['approveStat'])){
  $userID = $this->input->post('userID');
  $timeID = $this->input->post('approveStat');
  $approval = $this->input->post('approval');

  if ($approval == 'pendingWHome') {
      $insStat = 'Work at Home';
      $insApprove = 'approveWHome';

  }elseif ($approval == 'pendingFWork') {
      $insStat = 'Field Work';
      $insApprove ='approveFWork';

  }elseif ($approval == 'pendingALeave') {
      $insStat = 'Authorized Leave';
      $insApprove = 'approveALeave'; 

  }elseif ($approval == 'pendingHoliday') {
      $insStat = 'Non-Working Holiday';
      $insApprove = 'approveHoliday';
  }

  $this->admin->verifyNoti($userID, $timeID, $insApprove, $insStat, $datenow);
  redirect('admin/pending');

}
```

Model:

```
 function verifyNoti($userID, $timeID, $insApprove, $insStat, $year_num)
{
$jd=cal_to_jd(CAL_GREGORIAN,date('m'),date('d'),date('Y'));
$today=(jddayofweek($jd,1));
//get weekday only
$dateOrder = date("Ymd");
//User for date ordering

$verify = array(
  'status' => $insStat,
  'ApprovalStat' => $insApprove
);

$this -> db -> where('timeId', $timeID);
$query = $this->db->update('timerecord', $verify);
}

function getNotification()
{
 $this -> db -> select('users.*');
 $this -> db -> select('timerecord.*');
 $this -> db -> from('users');
 $this -> db -> join('timerecord', 'users.id = timerecord.id', 'left');
 $this -> db -> where('timerecord.ApprovalStat !=', '');
 $this -> db -> where('timerecord.ApprovalStat !=', 'approveFWork');
 $this -> db -> where('timerecord.ApprovalStat !=', 'approveWHome');
 $this -> db -> where('timerecord.ApprovalStat !=', 'approveALeave');
 $this -> db -> where('timerecord.ApprovalStat !=', 'approveHoliday');
 $this -> db -> order_by('timerecord.dateOrder', 'DESC');

 $query = $this -> db -> get();
 return $query->result();
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of you buttons name the same in the rows (approveStat), if you set the type to submit, then the button value will be posted where clicked (current row).
if you add a hidden field or checkbox with array name, you can use approveAll button (if you want this below)

in php only that checkbox value will post where is checked -> process it -> build update array -> win
[sort how too](http://davidwalsh.name/checkbox-form-input-arrays)

aslo use switch-case insted of elseif ;-)